# getView() never called on custom adapter

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I am aware that other people have asked this question, but I have looked at other solutions and still can't get it to work.

Adapter code:

```
private class CustomTextAndImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<String> timeArrayList;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> weatherIconArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> descriptionArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> tempArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> popArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> windSpeedArrayList;

    public final void setTimeArrayList(ArrayList<String> timeArrayList)
    {
        this.timeArrayList = timeArrayList;
    }

    public final void setDescriptionArrayList(ArrayList<String> descriptionArrayList)
    {
        this.descriptionArrayList = descriptionArrayList;
    }

    public final void setTempArrayList(ArrayList<String> tempArrayList)
    {
        this.tempArrayList = tempArrayList;
    }

    public final void setPopArrayList(ArrayList<String> popArrayList)
    {
        this.popArrayList = popArrayList;
    }

    public final void setWindSpeedArrayList(ArrayList<String> windSpeedArrayList)
    {
        this.windSpeedArrayList = windSpeedArrayList;
    }

    public final void setWeatherIconArrayList(ArrayList<Bitmap> weatherIconArrayList)
    {
        this.weatherIconArrayList = weatherIconArrayList;
    }

    public CustomTextAndImageAdapter(Context context, Activity activity, int resource)
    {
        super(context, resource);
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "getView() method called");
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemlistrow, null, false);

        TextView timeTextView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        timeTextView.setText(timeArrayList.get(position));
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Time text view text = " + timeArrayList.get(position));

        ImageView iconImageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.weatherIcon);
        iconImageView.setImageBitmap(weatherIconArrayList.get(position));

        TextView descriptionTextView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        descriptionTextView.setText(descriptionArrayList.get(position));

        TextView tempTextView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.temp);
        tempTextView.setText(tempArrayList.get(position));

        TextView popTextView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.pop);
        popTextView.setText(popArrayList.get(position));

        TextView windSpeedTextView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.windSpeed);
        windSpeedTextView.setText(windSpeedArrayList.get(position));

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

List item layout (itemlistrow.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/time" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/weatherIcon"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sunny"
                android:id="@+id/description"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="11 C"
                android:id="@+id/temp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text = "Rain:"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text = "Wind:"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id = "@+id/pop"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text = "@+id/windSpeed"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In some of the other solutions, it mentions overriding getCount().  Is this what I am doing wrong?  If so, how would I know what to put in for getCount(), as there are multiple different ArrayLists used.  Is it a case of picking one of them, as they are all the same length, e.g. timeArrayList.size()?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The getView() method of ArrayAdapter is not getting called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730328/the-getview-method-of-arrayadapter-is-not-getting-called)

Comment: Instead of getter and setter you can pass the list to the adapter constructor. In the super call `super(context, resource,yourlist)`. Note; if you update your underlying data the populates the list don't forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.

Comment: @Michael Nares Dont pass resourceid in super of Constructor. thats y getView is Not Called. Refer here http://coderzpassion.com/android-listview-with-image-and-text/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using multiple `ArrayList` objects like that kind of defeats the purpose of using an `ArrayAdapter`, whose idea is to have a single source of items. Not to mention that the code right now doesn't look nice at all.

I'd suggest to first create a `Weather` object that will hold your data:

```
public class Weather {
    private String time;
    private Bitmap weatherIcon;
    private String description;
    private String temp;
    private String pop;
    private String windSpeed;

    // build object here, provide getters, etc....
    .....
}
```

Than your `adapter` can be transformed to something simpler like this:

```
private class CustomTextAndImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Weather>
{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomTextAndImageAdapter(Context context, Activity activity, int resource, List<Weather> items)
    {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemlistrow, null, false);

        TextView timeTextView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        timeTextView.setText(getItem(position).getTime());

        ImageView iconImageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.weatherIcon);
        iconImageView.setImageBitmap(getItem(position).getWeatherIcon());

        ........

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Main difference is that it's now an `ArrayAdapter<Weather>` and that you're passing the arguments directly in the `constructor` of the adapter. Users of the adapter now have to call just 1 constructor, instead of all the final methods that had to be called before.

The other major difference is that you're passing the `items` list to the super class. Now your `adapter` knows it's size (internally `getCount()` will be == `items.size()`) so `getView()` will be called appropriately.

As a final thought - the `adapter` is still not using the `ViewHolder` pattern, which you should totally implement! There's been numerous posts for it, so just search a bit and you'll find it.

Comment: No, you don't need to. It'll return the appropriate `Weather` object from the list you pass in the constructor. Lastly - I'd really stress the importance of implementing the `ViewHolder` pattern :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good way to populate a `ListView` using an adapter which populates the data from multiple `ArrayList`. Generally we use a single source of dataset to be passed to an adapter in case of showing a list in Android.

So in your case, when you'll call the `notifyDatasetChanged` it shouldn't take effect in the list properly as far as I can guess.

`notifyDatasetChanged` basically calls the `getCount` function of the adapter and checks if the size of the `ArrayList` associated with the adapter is changed or not. If the size of the `ArrayList` is changed, it refreshes the `ListView` and the `getView` function gets called.

In your case, I don't see any `getCount` function though. `getCount` usually returns the size of the `ArrayList` associated with the adapter.

So I would suggest, using a single `ArrayList` to be passed to the adapter. You can merge multiple `ArrayList` and can use one joined `HashMap` in your case too. Its your decision, exactly how you can pass a single list of your dataset to the adapter to populate them into a `ListView`.

Comment: getCount () is internally called if you provide proper params in the super call. can be checked by looking at the ArrayAdapter code. you can have pojos with setter and getter instead of all those array lists.